# How to use a dihedral angle to find $x$, $y$, and $z$ coordinates

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

In the below diagram, the angle $\gamma$ represents the dihedral angle between the plane formed by $r_1R$ and the plane formed by $r_2R$. The origin is at the intersection between $r_1$ and $R$.

I know that the $x$ and $y$ coordinates for points $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ have $\cos(\alpha)$, $\sin(\alpha)$, $\cos(\beta)$, and $\sin(\beta)$ terms, but I am unsure how to incorporate the dihedral angle, $\gamma$, for $x$, $y$, and $z$.

[image: The given variables for this example]

Comment: What is $R$ here?

Comment: I think $R$ is the longest dimenstion of the cuboid

Comment: @asleep_fox did my answer serve you?

Answer (score 0):

To get $C$ and $D$ from $A$ and $B$, assume $\vec{A} = -\vec{B} = -\frac{r_1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sin(\alpha)\\ \cos(\alpha)\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

**(1)** Rotate the Line $AB$ around the $x$-axis $\gamma$ degrees.

[Rotating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) $\vec{A}$ (the line from the origin $0$ to the point $A$) by an angle of $\gamma$ around the $x$-axis yields $$\vec{A'}=-\frac{r_1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sin(\alpha)\\ \cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\\\cos(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\end{bmatrix}, $$
now the line between $0$ and $A'$ is parallel to the line $CD$.

**(2)** Change the size of $r_1$ to $r_2$ or scale $r_1$ by $\frac{r_2}{r_1}$.

[Scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)) $\vec{A'}$ with $\frac{r_2}{r_1}$ yields $$\vec{A''}=-\frac{r_2}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sin(\alpha)\\ \cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\\\cos(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\end{bmatrix}.$$

**(3)** Move (the rotated and scaled line $AB$) exactly $R$ units along the positive $x-$direction

[Adding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction) $R$ units along the positive $x-$direction to $\vec{A''}$ we get

$$\vec{C}=-\vec{D}=-\frac{r_2}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sin(\alpha)-\frac{2}{r_2}R\\ \cos(\alpha)\cos(\gamma)\\\cos(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)\end{bmatrix}. $$

***EDIT***
[image: 3D dihedral angle]
$r(x)=r_1 + (r_2-r_1)\cdot\left(\frac{x}{R}\right)$

Comment: If gamma is the dihedral angle between the planes formed by AB and CD, why is the line between 0 and A' parallel to the line of CD? Wouldn't they be off by the angle gamma?

Comment: Off by the angle gamma are the planes, which are (1) formed by AB and R and (2) formed by CD and R. If we rotate the line AB about the origin around the x-Axis by gamma, then we get a line A'B', which is parallel to the line CD. The line segments between the origin and A' or B' are also parallel to the line CD. I will put some sketches later on to illustrate the process